# MVC 5 Data was not pass to mode from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a productModelView which contains 2 Model.All the data in the product and inventory fields  was not populated to the model when pass back to the model in the controller.

```
 public class ProductDetails
{
    public ProductsTb Product { get; set; }
    public InventoryTb ProductInventory { get; set; }
  public List<ItemTypeLibrary> ProductTypeList { get; set; }
}
```

To make code short.i will just show 1 attribute which is inside the productsTB

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {//load up create page to populate product type list
        ProductDetails pd = new ProductDetails();
        pd.ProductTypeList = db.ItemTypeLibraries.ToList();
        return View(pd);
    }

  [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "productID,ArticleID,ProductType,ProductName")] ProductDetails productsTb)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.ProductsTbs.Add(productsTb.Product);
            db.SaveChanges();
            db.InventoryTbs.Add(productsTb.ProductInventory);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(productsTb);
    }
@model RicmasNet.Models.Product.ProductDetails
```

### Create

```
@model RicmasNet.Models.Product.ProductDetails
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {




<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>ProductsTb</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.ArticleID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.ArticleID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.ArticleID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.ProductType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.DropDownListFor(model =>model.Product.ProductType, new SelectList(Model.ProductTypeList,"ItemTypeId","ItemTypeName"), "Select a Type...", new { @style = "width:500px" })


         @*   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductType, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductTypeList, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.ProductName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.ProductName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.ProductName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.ProductLocation, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.ProductLocation, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.ProductLocation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.ProductBrand, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.ProductBrand, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.ProductBrand, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.ProductOrigin, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.ProductOrigin, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.ProductOrigin, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.ProductCost, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.ProductCost, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.ProductCost, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.ProductRetailPrice, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.ProductRetailPrice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.ProductRetailPrice, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.ProductDealerPrice, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.ProductDealerPrice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.ProductDealerPrice, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.ProductWeight, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.ProductWeight, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.ProductDescEnglish, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.ProductDescEnglish, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.ProductDescNonEnglish, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.ProductDescNonEnglish, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.ProductPicPath, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.ProductPicPath, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

        </div>
    </div>


                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Product.IsDelete)
           @Model.Product.IsDelete == true;

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.ProductPicPath2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.ProductPicPath2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.ProductPicPath3, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.ProductPicPath3, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.ProductVideo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.ProductVideo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.COC, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.COC, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.COC, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.COCIssue, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.COCIssue, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.COCExpireDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.COCExpireDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.COCType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.COCType, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.COCRF, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.COCRF)

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.EAN, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.EAN, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>}
```

Comment: The only form field is for the `model.Product.ArticleID` field.  If that's the only value being sent to the server, then that's the only value the server is going to have.

Comment: add complete models and views code.

Comment: added whole view code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear from what you posted as to what isn't being bound, but if you are expecting the entire viewmodel, then remove the `Bind(Include...)` attribute. It's not needed in that case.

Comment: Obviously OP expecting entire viewModel but I don't see how your suggestion is going to help when model is not sent in the request...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Because the comment in the question specifically states that they are not listing every attribute in the form group to save space.

Comment: I see it now... very strange move on OP part - remove useful code from sample and keep unrelated `ValidationMessageFor...`. Maybe they will read about [MCVE] at some point.

Comment: i think ATerry's suggestion works. I can see data are populated to model.products.But the tricky part is passing value from producttype.At least i am there somehow.

Comment: @AizhongChen I don't see producttypelist in your model for the razor helper dropdownlistfor. Did you mean x.product.producttype there?

Comment: hi sorry. i removed it just now to not to confuse people.added back now.

Comment: i also noticed that by removing the bind(include) model.validstate always return false if i didnt fill everything up.Is that normal?

Comment: solved. change producttypelist to producttype to append selected value to product model

Comment: @aizhong only if you have require attributes on all your properties in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is, use FormCollection instead of passing the model, in case of custom attributes to include object.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection form)
    {
        // here you can retrieve attributes from form and assign to your object
        productsTb.Id = form["Id"]; // it should match the name of tag in View

        return View(productsTb);
    }
```